# Force python mysql.connector to raise an exception when failing a SQL transaction

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

Python's mysql.connector does not raise when `INSERT`ing a new row in a table that does not exist, neither it does when the syntax is wrong.
How can I force it to raise?

MWE:

```
import mysql.connector

connection_params = dict(user="myself", host="localhost")
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**connection_params)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE IDontExist (Col1, Col2) VALUES (1, 2)"
conn.close()
```

When I run this, either into the interpreter or through a script, it just runs. without.
I want the `cursor.execute` to raise.

Versions: Python: 3.9.7, mysql.connector: 8.0.27, mysql: 8.0.29

Comment: It won't raise until you call `conn.commit()`.  At that point you must catch the exception and call conn.rollback()`.

Comment: I tested your example with Python 3.10, MySQL 8.0.29, mysql.connector 8.0.28. There are some mistakes in your code (e.g. `get_cursor()` instead of `cursor()`), but once I fixed them, it does throw an exception at the syntax error.

Comment: @BillKarwin yeah sorry I just wrote directly in SO by hand. There was no get_cursor in my original code. I corrected the question btw.